# Question for the default notations in mathematics to represent variables, such as $n$ for an integer and $z$ for a complex number.

Tags: notation

I just read an article about the notations in mathematics. There are some articles like [this one](https://mathvault.ca/hub/higher-math/math-symbols/) about the mathematical notations. Furthermore, [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/proofs/writingtips.pdf) gives another further advise about writing.

In many places (textbooks, math contests, the questions here, etc.) we commonly use some fixed notations to represent some kinds of the variables (we limit the range of discussion in math forums or in math paper or some contexts like this, not including physics and other subjects.) For example, we commonly use $n$ to represent an integer, $p$ for a prime, $z$ for complex numbers, but we less likely use $n$ to represent a complex number or $z$ to represent a prime. So can I ask how this "regulation" formed or why do we have this common sense? I tried to find it in this stack exchange, but I can't find one... so I ask this question here.

Comment: i think these customs formed because people are impatient, and life is short. For newbies this is frustrating, but for the pros these tacit assumptions lead to efficiency.

Comment: It really depends on context. For example, in an elementary physics class, $s$ is used as a real number typically describing the displacement of a particle undergoing motion along a straight line. In complex analysis, Riemann introduced the notation $s=\sigma+it$ (why not $\sigma=s+it$ or $s=\sigma+i\tau$ I'm not sure) for a complex number rather than $z$. So, the answer is always context.

Comment: @peek-a-boo You are right, in physics they are using another set of notations... but I am curious that why in mathematics the notation is just like that (like... where are they come from? how was it formed? etc.) but thank you for mentioning this, I am going to add some clarification.